# Realm Object Server io.realm.sync.auth error 3 using custom credentials

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm hosting a Realm Object Server on aws, and I'm getting the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (io.realm.sync.auth error 3.)` when trying to log in a `SyncUser`. Here is my code:

```
func userCredentials() -> SyncCredentials? {
    var credentials: SyncCredentials?
    SpotifyLogin.shared.getAccessToken { (accessToken, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("⚠️ Unable to get realm user, no Spotify access token")
        } else {
            credentials = SyncCredentials(customToken: accessToken!, provider: Provider("Spotify"))
        }
    }
    return credentials
}
```

This function returns the credentials to be used below when logging in:

```
if let credentials = RealmManager.shared.userCredentials() {
        SyncUser.logIn(with: credentials, server: RealmManager.shared.syncAuthURL) { user, error in
            if let user = user {
                // Do something with user object
            } else {
                // Print error
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is occurring when `login(with:server:)` is called. I'm unsure what the root of the problem is due to the vague error message but I can confirm that my server url is correct and the server is running when this error occurs.